# ansible:Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '10.90.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

i want to use the key login some host, but some err happened

my files is this below:

```
[jenkins@ci-jenkins-slave-dev test]$ ls
ansible.cfg  hosts  test.yml
```

my hosts file:

```
[jenkins@ci-jenkins-slave-dev test]$ cat hosts
[controller]
10.90.0.2 ssh_key_pass=passw0rd ansible_ssh_user=root
```

my playbook:

```
[jenkins@ci-jenkins-slave-dev test]$ cat test.yml
---

- name: test
  hosts: controller
  tasks:
    - name: add key
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

when run playbook :

```
[jenkins@ci-jenkins-slave-dev test]$ ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [test] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add key] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.90.0.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '10.90.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/jenkins/ansible-test/test/test.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.90.0.2                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

**I can use "ssh root@10.90.0.2 "and input "passw0rd" to login but ansible can't ,i want to know what's wrong ？**

my ansible.cfg :

```
[jenkins@ci-jenkins-slave-dev test]$ cat ansible.cfg
# config file for ansible -- http://ansible.com/
# ==============================================

# nearly all parameters can be overridden in ansible-playbook
# or with command line flags. ansible will read ANSIBLE_CONFIG,
# ansible.cfg in the current working directory, .ansible.cfg in
# the home directory or /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, whichever it
# finds first

[defaults]

# some basic default values...

hostfile       = ./hosts
library        = /usr/share/ansible
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 5
poll_interval  = 15
sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
transport      = smart
remote_port    = 22
module_lang    = C

# plays will gather facts by default, which contain information about
# the remote system.
#
# smart - gather by default, but don't regather if already gathered
# implicit - gather by default, turn off with gather_facts: False
# explicit - do not gather by default, must say gather_facts: True
gathering = explicit

# additional paths to search for roles in, colon separated
#roles_path    = /etc/ansible/roles

# uncomment this to disable SSH key host checking
host_key_checking = False

# change this for alternative sudo implementations
sudo_exe = sudo

# what flags to pass to sudo
#sudo_flags = -H

# SSH timeout
timeout = 10

# default user to use for playbooks if user is not specified
# (/usr/bin/ansible will use current user as default)
remote_user = root

# logging is off by default unless this path is defined
# if so defined, consider logrotate
#log_path = /var/log/ansible.log

# default module name for /usr/bin/ansible
#module_name = command

# use this shell for commands executed under sudo
# you may need to change this to bin/bash in rare instances
# if sudo is constrained
#executable = /bin/sh

# if inventory variables overlap, does the higher precedence one win
# or are hash values merged together?  The default is 'replace' but
# this can also be set to 'merge'.
#hash_behaviour = replace

# list any Jinja2 extensions to enable here:
#jinja2_extensions = jinja2.ext.do,jinja2.ext.i18n

# if set, always use this private key file for authentication, same as
# if passing --private-key to ansible or ansible-playbook
private_key_file = ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# format of string {{ ansible_managed }} available within Jinja2
# templates indicates to users editing templates files will be replaced.
# replacing {file}, {host} and {uid} and strftime codes with proper values.
ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}

# by default, ansible-playbook will display "Skipping [host]" if it determines a task
# should not be run on a host.  Set this to "False" if you don't want to see these "Skipping"
# messages. NOTE: the task header will still be shown regardless of whether or not the
# task is skipped.
#display_skipped_hosts = True

# by default (as of 1.3), Ansible will raise errors when attempting to dereference
# Jinja2 variables that are not set in templates or action lines. Uncomment this line
# to revert the behavior to pre-1.3.
#error_on_undefined_vars = False

# by default (as of 1.6), Ansible may display warnings based on the configuration of the
# system running ansible itself. This may include warnings about 3rd party packages or
# other conditions that should be resolved if possible.
# to disable these warnings, set the following value to False:
#system_warnings = True

# by default (as of 1.4), Ansible may display deprecation warnings for language
# features that should no longer be used and will be removed in future versions.
# to disable these warnings, set the following value to False:
#deprecation_warnings = True

# set plugin path directories here, separate with colons
action_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/action_plugins
callback_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/callback_plugins
connection_plugins = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/connection_plugins
lookup_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/lookup_plugins
vars_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/vars_plugins
filter_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/filter_plugins

# don't like cows?  that's unfortunate.
# set to 1 if you don't want cowsay support or export ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1
#nocows = 1

# don't like colors either?
# set to 1 if you don't want colors, or export ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=1
#nocolor = 1

# the CA certificate path used for validating SSL certs. This path
# should exist on the controlling node, not the target nodes
# common locations:
# RHEL/CentOS: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
# Fedora     : /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
# Ubuntu     : /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/cacert.org.crt
#ca_file_path =

# the http user-agent string to use when fetching urls. Some web server
# operators block the default urllib user agent as it is frequently used
# by malicious attacks/scripts, so we set it to something unique to
# avoid issues.
#http_user_agent = ansible-agent

[paramiko_connection]

# uncomment this line to cause the paramiko connection plugin to not record new host
# keys encountered.  Increases performance on new host additions.  Setting works independently of the
# host key checking setting above.
record_host_keys=False

# by default, Ansible requests a pseudo-terminal for commands executed under sudo. Uncomment this
# line to disable this behaviour.
#pty=False

[ssh_connection]

# ssh arguments to use
# Leaving off ControlPersist will result in poor performance, so use
# paramiko on older platforms rather than removing it
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

# The path to use for the ControlPath sockets. This defaults to
# "%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r", however on some systems with
# very long hostnames or very long path names (caused by long user names or
# deeply nested home directories) this can exceed the character limit on
# file socket names (108 characters for most platforms). In that case, you
# may wish to shorten the string below.
#
# Example:
# control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
#control_path = %(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r

# Enabling pipelining reduces the number of SSH operations required to
# execute a module on the remote server. This can result in a significant
# performance improvement when enabled, however when using "sudo:" you must
# first disable 'requiretty' in /etc/sudoers
#
# By default, this option is disabled to preserve compatibility with
# sudoers configurations that have requiretty (the default on many distros).
#
#pipelining = False

# if True, make ansible use scp if the connection type is ssh
# (default is sftp)
#scp_if_ssh = True

[accelerate]
accelerate_port = 5099
accelerate_timeout = 30
accelerate_connect_timeout = 5.0

# The daemon timeout is measured in minutes. This time is measured
# from the last activity to the accelerate daemon.
accelerate_daemon_timeout = 30

# If set to yes, accelerate_multi_key will allow multiple
# private keys to be uploaded to it, though each user must
# have access to the system via SSH to add a new key. The default
# is "no".
#accelerate_multi_key = yes
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know, and I will add

Answer (score 3):

The variable for password is `ansible_ssh_pass`, but you use `ssh_key_pass`.

Try with this inventory:

```
[controller]
10.90.0.2 ansible_ssh_pass=passw0rd ansible_ssh_user=root
```

Comment: thanks a lot , should be ansible_ssh_pass not ssh_key_pass

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem. I missed a step.

```
ssh-copy-id localhost
```

Then you can successfully run,

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts simple-docker-project.yml --check
```